# modsecurity chaining and OR logic

Tags: linux, apache, security, apache2, mod-security

is there a way to chain SecRules and create OR AND complex logic ? like

> (secrule1 OR secrule2) AND secrule3

The only way I see it is by repeating chained (used for AND) code blocks which can be quite a hassle when dealing with multiple lines.

thanks

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?